# How reusing connections results in efficient networking on android?

Tags: android, performance, android-networking

I was going through the android docs for [Efficient Network Access](https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html). I got the data prefetching part as well as the batch transfer approach, basic crux behind both of them being

`Don't keep the network radio in active state all the time. let it go to stand by state at regular intervals`

However, proceeding to the next section, [Reduce Connections](https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html#ReduceConnections), I am still not clear with some of the statements. They are:

> Reusing connections also allows the network to more intelligently react to congestion and related network data issues

and

> it would be more efficient to make a single request for every news article to be returned in a single request / response than to make multiple queries for several news categories

and

> A useful compromise is not to close the connection immediately, but to still close it before the inherent timeout expires

Can someone please explain these statements in detail?

Comment: Regarding the second quote, a single request/response for N items will involve less data transfer than will N requests/responses for 1 item each, as each request and response adds overhead (e.g., HTTP headers). This gets worse if you are not reusing connections and we have to create and tear down sockets for each request/response. And, this gets all the worse if you are using HTTPS (which you should!), as we have to do all of the TLS handshaking N times.

Comment: hmm, makes sense. I was only thinking in the direction of whether the duration for which network radio keeps awake will be reduced. I think it's not guarranteed, but on average it definitely will. In case where I am getting the whole data in just 1 request, server might also take longer to send response. But considering the handshake times also as you mentioned, it's a no-brainer then to use a single connection.